# Multiple advices in single Aspect for same method execution pointcut - Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, reflection, spring-aop

I just want to understand something related to Spring AOP advice ordering.In the docs it says

> When two pieces of advice defined in the same aspect both need to run at the same join point, the ordering is undefined (**since there is no way to retrieve the declaration order via reflection for javac-compiled classes**). Consider collapsing such advice methods into one advice method per join point in each aspect class, or refactor the pieces of advice into separate aspect classes - which can be ordered at the aspect level.

I get that we cannot define multiple advices for same pointcut in one Aspect.I just want to understand what does it mean by **there is no way to retrieve the declaration order via reflection for javac-compiled classes** ?.

I have put @Order annotations on multiple advices on same pointcut in one Aspect and clearly defined the orders from 1 to 3.Why it cannot get this numeric order value when it reads @Order annotations in the Aspect class via reflection and properly call the advices in correct order? Can any body please make me understand this.Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That's mean, that the order is undefined if not explicitly specified. 
[`@Order`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) annotation has the runtime retention:

```
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Target(value={TYPE,METHOD,FIELD})
public @interface Order
```

And it's possible to read order via reflection.